# How to read txt file in local storage in Ionic

Tags: ionic3

I'm making a simple app with Ionic 3 to read a .txt file stored in the device, for example in Downloads folder. I want to read the file and write it in the screen.

I've already used FileChooser and FileOpener but those open the file with a text editor. I also tried with File but I was getting some errors.

I don't want to open this file with another app, I just to read the file in my app.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. The way it worked was indeed with File. The problem was that I was installing the wrong way. I was installing like this:

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/file
```

And then I tried to import:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
```

or:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
```

Both ways didn't work. Since the problem was in the npm installation I had to uninstall it and install in a different way:

```
npm uninstall @ionic-native/file
npm install --save @ionic-native/file@4
```

And then simply import it:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
```

I solved this when I found this other problem

[How to fix "Object(...) is not a function error" using PayPal in Ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54838971/how-to-fix-object-is-not-a-function-error-using-paypal-in-ionic-3)

Well that's it.
Thanks everybody!